# Services lifecycle (destroy a service)

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-module

My application has an architecture as follows:
[image]

Once the user log in, I navigate to the **MainModule** (lazy) where I register the services used in the **MainModule**'s components.
**CarService** caches the result of the webservice so, if the user logs out, I need this service to be destroyed.
When the user logs out I navigate to the **LoginModolue**.

I thought that navigating to the **LoginModule**, the **MainModule** would have been destroyed (in fact I register it in the **MainModule**, not in the AppModule) but I noticed that if I log in again the old cache is still there.
Is this normal?
Shouldn't be destroyed the services provided in the **MainModule** when I navigate to the **LoginModule**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would expect that to happen, unfortunately because of the nature of lazy modules, this is not what happens, read [here](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-by-lazy-loading-modules) why not. Basically the lazy loaded module stays in the memory.

What you can do however is put the provider on the main component view:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     MainComponent
  ]
})
export class MainModule {}

@Component({
  //...
  providers: [ CarService ]
})
export class MainComponent {}
```

This will destroy the `CarService` instance when the `MainComponent` gets destroyed

Answer (score 2):

That's not the case. Moving to some other module won't mean that the previously Lazy Loaded Module will be destroyed. It would still remain. That's why Angular doesn't request for the Chunk of that Lazy Loaded Module when we try to navigate again to that Module.

The service will also remain in the memory. Only when the user manually reloads the App, will the service get reinitialized.

You'll have to manually clean the cache before navigating the user to the `/login` route. The ideal place for doing this can be in the `ngOnDestroy` of the Component that you're navigating away from.